# Яка правильна пунктуація у словосполученні «купуй як зазвичай»?

Tags: правопис, пунктуація

Чи ставиться кома перед "як" у виразі *"купуй як зазвичай"*?

Comment: Ласкаво просимо до сайту Ukrainian Language.SE! Чи робили ви спробу самостійного пошуку відповіді на це запитання? Наша спільнота найкраще сприймає запитання, що містять бодай спробу самостійно розібратися з запропонованою проблемою. Одним із можливих прикладів може бути, коли ви переглянули кілька різних джерел, і вони суперечать один одному.

Comment: Високосний рік - це рік, в якому триста шістдесят днів, а не триста шістдесят п'ять як зазвичай. Чи потрібна кома перед як?

Comment: @name, у Вашому випадку, я вважаю, кома потрібна.

Comment: [Технічне обговорення](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133831/discussion-on-question-by-------) (туди перенесено частину коментарів).

Answer (score 4):

«Як зазвичай» може відігравати одну з двох ролей:

1. Або бути вставною конструкцією, що щось уточнює, але істотно не впливає на сенс речення:

   > Як зазвичай, я встав о сьомій ранку.

   У таких випадках «к зазвичай» виділяється комами.
2. Або виконувати функцію члена речення, наприклад, обставини, що передає спосіб дії, без якого сенс речення істотно зміниться:

   > Я встав (як? о котрій годині?) як зазвичай.

   У таких випадках «к зазвичай» не виділяється комами.

У Вас може скластися враження, що відмінність між двома вищенаведеними прикладами в наявності обставини «о сьомій ранку». Але насправді відмінність зовсім не в цьому. Одну й ту саму фразу «я встав[,] як зазвичай» ми можемо написати двома способами — з без коми й із комою — просто сенс буде різний: «я встав як зазвичай» = «я встав звичайним чином» — тут «як зазвичай» передає спосіб дії (тобто замість того, щоб явно писати «я встав з правої ноги» або «я встав о сьомій ранку» абощо, я пишу скорочено, маючи на увазі, що читач знає спосіб, яким я це зазвичай роблю, але сенс речення в тому, що я роблю це *саме цим способом*); «я встав, як зазвичай» = «я встав. Як зазвичай» — тут сенс речення лише в тому, що я встав (при цьому мимохідь відзначається, що зазвичай я теж встаю, а не лежу весь день, але про спосіб вставання нічого не мовиться). Або ж: «я встав, як звичайно, о сьомій годині» — сенс речення в тому, що я встав о сьомій годині (і мимохідь відзначається, що зазвичай я теж так роблю»); «я встав як зазвичай — о сьомій годині» — сенс речення в тому, що я встав як зазвичай («як зазвичай» — тут спосіб дії; читач, можливо, знає, як саме я зазвичай встаю, але про всяк випадок далі пояснюється явно, що «як зазвичай» = «о сьомій годині»).

У Вашому випадку, імовірно, мова про те, щоб читач купував якимось (не названим явно) *звичайним для себе чином*. Тобто кома **зайва**. (Хоча суто теоретично мова може бути й про те, щоб читач просто *купував* (без уточнення способу), а не зраджував своїй звичці й переставав купувати, — у такому разі кома потрібна.) (Тобто якщо в «купуй[,] як зазвичай» оте «як зазвичай» — це спосіб купівлі, то кома зайва; якщо ж зміст речення — це просто «купуй», а «як зазвичай» — це несуттєве вточнення, то кома потрібна.)

Тобто іншими словами:

- «Я приїхав як зазвичай» = «я приїхав таким способом (у той час, на тому транспорті), як я зазвичай це роблю». («Я приїхав як зазвичай — останньою маршруткою» = «я приїхав таким способом, як я зазвичай це роблю, а саме: останньою маршруткою».)
- «Я приїхав, як зазвичай» = «я зазвичай приїжджаю — і цього разу я теж приїхав (просто приїхав, про спосіб ані слова)». («Я приїхав, як зазвичай, останньою маршруткою» = «я зазвичай приїжджаю останньою маршруткою — і цього разу я теж приїхав останньою маршруткою».)

У правописі 2019 року це регламентовано так (сс. [165](https://mon.gov.ua/storage/app/media/zagalna%20serednya/05062019-onovl-pravo.pdf#page=165) — [181](https://mon.gov.ua/storage/app/media/zagalna%20serednya/05062019-onovl-pravo.pdf#page=181)):

> ### § 158. КОМА (,)
>
> #### І. Кома в простому реченні
>
> У простому реченні комуставимов таких позиціях.
>
> <…>
>
> 12. Для виділення порівняльних зворотів, що вводяться сполучниками *як* (*як і*), *мов*, *мовби*, *наче*, *немов*, *неначе*, *ніби*, *буцімто* і т. ін., *ніж*: <…>
>
>     Примітка 1. **Виділяємо комами** звороти зі сполучником як уточнювального або узагальнювального  характеру  на  зразок *як  завжди*, *як  звичайно*,  *як  колись*, *як навмисно*, *як правило*, *як виняток* та ін.: *Дума — це віршований твір, виконуваний (як правило, соло) речитативом* (М. Рильський), **за винятком** тих, що входять до складу групи присудка або головного члена односкладного речення: *Заморозки ще восени тут бувають як правило*; *Це було допущено як виняток*; *Він це зробив як навмисно*.
>
>     <…>
>
>     Примітка 3. Коми перед порівняльними сполучниками **не ставимо**: <…> Про особливості пунктуації в реченнях з нерозкладними синтаксичними зворотами, подібними за будовою до складнопідрядних речень, на зразок *Робити як слід*, *Відбувалося невідомо що* і под. **див. § 158, ІІ, п. 3, прим. 4**.
>
>     <…>
>
> <…>
>
> #### ІІ. Кома ускладному реченні
>
> У складному реченні комуставимов таких позиціях.
>
> <…>
>
> 3. Для  відокремлення  частин  складнопідрядного  речення  (підрядну частину відокремлюємо комою  з одного боку  або,  якщо  вона розташована всередині головної частини, з обох боків): <…>
>
>    Примітка  4. Коми перед  підрядним  сполучником  або  сполучним  словом  **не ставимо** в  синтаксично  нерозкладних  конструкціях,  подібних  за будовою  до складнопідрядних  речень  і  похідних  від  них (колишні  підрядні  частини  виконують  тут функцію членів речення): *робити як слід (як треба, як годиться, як належить, як має бути)*, *дивлячись хто (що, який, куди, скільки)*, *невідомо (не знати, невідь, хтозна) хто (що, куди, звідки, скільки)*, *хто як не він це знає (кому як не йому це відомо)*, *кричати що є сили (духу)*, *говорити все що попало (завгодно, доведеться, здумається)*, *роби що хочеш*, *будь що буде*, *іди куди хочеш*; *Нам є ще над чим працювати*; *І Остапові стало жалко Соломію, страх як жалко* (М. Коцюбинський); *[Сава:] […] Я піду відсіль, піду куди очі дивляться* (М. Костомаров).
>
>    <…>
>
> <…>

Comment: Мова йде про купівлю через кешбек-сервіс

повністю текст звучить так: Реєструйся — це просто:) Вибирай магазин Купуй як зазвичай Отримуй кешбек

У цьому випадку людина, купує звичним способом, проте через кешбек-сервіс.  Як бути у цьому випадку?

Comment: @НастяКравченко, у цьому випадку, я вважаю, коми не треба.